# Get a resulting array after removing similiar values from 2 different array

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

There are 2 set of code and each gives 2 different array

First set is this

```
$this->db->select('id');
$query = $this->db->get('user');
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $query->result());
echo "</pre>";
```

And gives the following result

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

)
```

Second one is this

```
$this->db->select('user_id');
$query_two = $this->db->get('request_user');
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $query_two->result());
echo "</pre>";
```

And gives the following result

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 1
        )

)
```

I wish to get final array that should not have the duplicate values, eg in the above 2 array 1 is common in both the array so it should not be there and in resulting array i should get only value 2

Answer (score 0):

You could take the following approach.  Make a list of ids from your second array.  And then use that list to filter the first. If an id is not in that list: keep it.

```
<?php

$one = [
    (object) ['id' => 1],
    (object) ['id' => 2],
];
$two = [
    (object) ['id' => 1],
];

$ids_in_two = [];
foreach($two as $val) {
    $ids_in_two[] = $val->id;
} 

$filtered = array_filter($one, function($val) use ($ids_in_two) {
    return !in_array($val->id, $ids_in_two);
});

var_dump($filtered);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```